# Как убрать квадратики по рамке datagridview в Metro Framework?

Tags: c#, datagridview, metro-framework

Как  убрать в datagridview tabs вот эти квадратики мини рамка сколько гуглил смотрел документацию ничего не нашел

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то не получается воспроизвести. Просто добавил DataGridView на форму и [не вижу квадратиков](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjoIb.png). Что у Вас под таблицей? Что будет если ее удалить? Может, попробуете создать [МСВП](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Не обратил внимания что в вопросе говорится о «datagridview tabs», а не просто о «datagridview». Можете объяснить что это такое?

Comment: @default locale  это в метрофреймворк табы и туда вставлен датагрид

Comment: Самостоятельно контрол с помощью DataTemplate надо перерисовывать. Подсказка: оригинал разметки лежит в исходниках. :)

Answer (score 0):

У вашего родительского элемента(в котором расположен ваш  datagridview) должно быть 2 параметра VerticalScrollbarSize и HorizontelscrolbarSize. Их нужно поставить на 0 в свойствах Properties.